# Whole layout messed up with relative width

Tags: html, css

I have following html for my site:
Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/3v66fv3u/1/ for the static site
and my approach of making the site responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/wba321bm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1 class="title">Headline</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="top">
                <img id="img_1" src="img_1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <img id="img_3" src="img_3.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <div class="about-text">
                <h3>small headline</h3>
                <p>actually a lot of text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div class="top">
                <a href="#"><img id="img_2" src="img_2.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <a href="#"><img id="img_4" src="img_4.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#"><img class="banner" src="banner.png"/></a>


  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my current css file:

```
html {
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1150px;
}

hr { 
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.middle {
    height: 597px;
    width: 550px;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.about-text {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.right {
    float: left;
}

.gallery {
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    height: 300px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* inline-block fügt standardmäßig 4px Padding hinzu
       das muss nun wieder subtrahiert werden. */
    margin-top: -4px;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#img_1 { 
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}

#img_2 { 
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

#img_3 { 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

#img_4 { 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
/* 827 x 178 */
.banner {
    width: 410px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

}
```

The website currently looks like this (with static layout):

[image]

Now I want to go away from the fixed layout and want to make the website responsive. However, when I give the fields a relative width the whole layout gets messed up...[image]

This is the css I tried to use to achieve the responsive layout:

```
html, body {
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}

hr { 
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.middle {
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.about-text {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.right {
    float: left;
}

.gallery {
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    /* inline-block fügt standardmäßig 4px Padding hinzu
       das muss nun wieder subtrahiert werden. */
    margin-top: -4px;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#img_1 { 
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
}

#img_2 { 
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

#img_3 { 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

#img_4 { 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
/* 827 x 178 */
.banner {
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be setting sizes on your images. You should have a layout structure that acts as a grid of containers, and the images should scale to fit the grid. The grid should stretch to contain your text, also.

Comment: @isherwood ah I didn't even know css has grids, looks really neat. Currently looking at articles / docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of WHICH elements get the percentage value. In my adaptation of your fiddle, I assigned `width: 30%` to `.left` and `right` (which are the containers for the images) and made the image width 100% to span the whole width of their containers.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/35n4dxqn/1/

Comment: Oh that is quite cool! But is it also possible to make the font scale depending on the size of the site?

Comment: you can use the `vw` (viewport width) unit for the font-size. I vw equals 1% of the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

well, when you give a or a division relative attribute it will be placed relative or according to the previous div i.e. it will not be independent from other divisions.

the solution if you want to make it responsive one forward and efficient way is to use Grid System (Bootstrap class).